# Android/Jetpack Compose/Dagger-Hilt: Dynamic ViewModel in a composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

The app I'm working on has a bar at the top that switches between a regular Jetpack Compose `LargeTopAppBar` and a custom `SearchAppBar` that I've built. The problem is that I couldn't figure out how to pass a search function from the current view model all the way "down" to the `SearchAppBar`, so I resorted to passing the view model itself – this way searching works!

However, I'd really like to re-use the app bar functionality on other screens that will rely on a different view model (albeit with the same implementation of the search functionality).

The question I have for you, therefore, is this:

**Is it possible to add a Hilt view model as a parameter, without specifying the view model type (i.e. `viewmodel: PreviousArticlesViewModel`)?**

##### The MainAppBar, which decides whether to show the regular LargeTopAppBar or the custom SearchAppBar (below)

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainAppBar(
    searchWidgetState: SearchWidgetState,
    onCloseClicked: () -> Unit,
    onSearchTriggered: () -> Unit,
    titleText: String,
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior
) {
    AnimatedContent(
        targetState = searchWidgetState,
        transitionSpec = {/* TransitionSpecs */
        }
    ) { targetState ->
        when (targetState) {
            SearchWidgetState.CLOSED -> {
                DefaultAppBar(
                    titleText = titleText,
                    onSearchClicked = onSearchTriggered,
                    scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
                )
            }
            SearchWidgetState.OPENED -> {
                SearchAppBar(
                    onCloseClicked = onCloseClicked
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

##### SearchAppBar

**Here I'm passing the view model directly, but I'd rather it be dynamic, so that the SearchAppBar fun can be reused with other views that rely on other view models**

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchAppBar(
    onCloseClicked: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: PreviousArticlesViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val searchText by viewModel.searchText.collectAsState()

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant
    ) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = searchText,
            // THIS is the function that needs to be passed to the SearchAppBar from the view model
            // passing viewmodel.SearchTextChange(it) doesn't work and I can't figure out why.
            onValueChange = viewModel::onSearchTextChange
        /* ......... */
            )
    }
}
```

##### PreviousArticlesViewModel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class PreviousArticlesViewModel @Inject constructor (
    private val repository: AphorismRepository
): ViewModel() {

    // SEARCH
    private val _searchText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val searchText = _searchText.asStateFlow()

    private var _previousArticles = MutableStateFlow(listOf<ArticleAndImage>())
    val previousArticles = searchText
        .combine(_previousArticles) { text, Articles ->
            if(text.isBlank()) {
                Articles
            } else {
                Articles.filter {
                    it.matchesSearchQuery(text)
                }
            }
        }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
            _previousArticles.value
        )

    // The reason the search functionality is in this view model and not in a separate one
    // is because the _previousArticles var is being populated at init{} from the repository
    fun onSearchTextChange(text: String) {
        _searchText.value = text
    }

}
```